How does logstash process json files exported by datagrip?
json file
[
    {
      "primary_key": 1,
      "A_NUMBER": "79061619077",
      "B_NUMBER": "79179906721",
      "CALL_DURATION": "562",
      "CALL_START_DATE": "Oct 30, 2019 @ 22:59:19.000"
    },
    {
      "primary_key": 2,
      "A_NUMBER": "79603335956",
      "B_NUMBER": "79879946257",
      "CALL_DURATION": "197",
      "CALL_START_DATE": "Oct 30, 2019 @ 22:58:00.000"
    }
]

Please tell me how to write conf file parsing. The official demo json format is
{"k":1}
{"k":1}
This way, my format is
[
{
"k":1
},
{
"k":1
}
]
